# Crash in UIGestureRecognizer related to WebView

Tags: webview, crash, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a random crash in Webview that happend a couple of times already.
(Test automation tools： Monkey)

It looks like it is related to UIWebView, but I have no clue what happened
 - any help is appreciated The crash seems to be known.

```
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      debugserver [406]

Date/Time:           2015-08-07 20:33:59.099 +0800
Launch Time:         2015-08-07 20:13:10.956 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000002e6beb8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001959d3bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x0000000188ff77b0 -[UIWebDocumentView selectionRectsForRange:] + 44
2   UIKit                           0x00000001890d03b0 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) distanceBetweenPoint:andRange:] + 88
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188dddcf4 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 3364
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188dc30d8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 272
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188c5c71c -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 576
6   UIKit                           0x00000001890cd4f8 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662 + 56
7   UIKit                           0x0000000188c20480 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 288
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188c1e82c _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2500
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188c5a894 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1040
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188c59f4c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 656
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188c2d188 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 260
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188ece320 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 15420
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188c2b69c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1712
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841a423c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841a34e0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841a1590 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840cd2d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
18  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d8eb6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188c92fa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
20  PxxSDK                  0x000000010009f144 0x100088000 + 94532
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019603ea04 start + 0
```

---

```
code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-07 19:47:25.688 +0800
Launch Time:         2015-08-07 18:30:53.690 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1841ec2d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1959c00e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1841f33a4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 220
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1841f0154 ___forwarding___ + 928
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1840f2ccc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   UIKit                           0x188ff77b4 -[UIWebDocumentView selectionRectsForRange:] + 48
6   UIKit                           0x1890d03b4 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) distanceBetweenPoint:andRange:] + 92
7   UIKit                           0x188dddcf8 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 3368
8   UIKit                           0x188dc30dc _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 276
9   UIKit                           0x188c5c720 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 580
10  UIKit                           0x1890cd4fc ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662 + 60
11  UIKit                           0x188c20484 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 292
12  UIKit                           0x188c1e830 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2504
13  UIKit                           0x188c5a898 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1044
14  UIKit                           0x188c59f50 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 660
15  UIKit                           0x188c2d18c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
16  UIKit                           0x188ece324 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 15424
17  UIKit                           0x188c2b6a0 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1716
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1841a4240 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1841a34e4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1841a1594 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1840cd2d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
22  GraphicsServices                0x18d8eb6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
23  UIKit                           0x188c92fac UIApplicationMain + 1488
24  PxxSDK                  0x100107148 0x1000f0000 + 94536
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x19603ea08 start + 4
```

---

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-07 18:30:15.419 +0800
Launch Time:         2015-08-07 18:10:52.612 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000014da98b0
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001959d3bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x0000000188c6ae48 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) containerIsBrowserView] + 48
2   UIKit                           0x0000000188c6add0 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) textDocument] + 44
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188c6acd0 -[UITextSelectionView selection] + 48
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188d5a6b8 -[UITextSelectionView inputViewDidChange] + 108
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841922c0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840cf44c _CFXNotificationPost + 2056
7   Foundation                      0x0000000184ffea7c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
8   UIKit                           0x000000018932bc8c -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 160
9   UIKit                           0x000000018932a390 -[UIInputWindowController performWithSafeTransitionFrames:] + 148
10  UIKit                           0x000000018932dac0 __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke644 + 460
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188c64770 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 404
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188c642d8 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188c641e0 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 100
14  UIKit                           0x000000018261bfec -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility animationDidStop:finished:] + 52
15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018857968c CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 292
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196011950 _dispatch_client_callout +         12
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196016208 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841a37f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001841a189c __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840cd2d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
21  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d8eb6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
22  UIKit                           0x0000000188c92fa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
23  PxxSDK                  0x0000000100067144 0x100050000 + 94532
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019603ea04 start + 0
```